# Javascript not work in session login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i try to alert, who want enter to member zone but not login and redirect them to index
this is my session code and phpalert is my implement method using javascript
then i test it javascript not display but it redirect to index.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("project1", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select user_id from users where user_id='$user_check'", $connection);
$user_std=mysql_query("select status from users where user_id='$user_check'",$connection);
$user_name=mysql_query("select name from users where user_id='$user_check'",$connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_std);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_name);
$login_session =$row['user_id'];
$name =$row3['name'];
$status=$row2['status'];
if(!isset($login_session)){

mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection

header('Location: index2.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
phpAlert("login before");
}
```

?>

Comment: *"Javascript not work in session login"* - JS, what JS? You mean whatever `phpAlert()` this is supposed to do? Firstly, you're doing a header and wanting to alert. Not going to work here. It's one or the other or use a JS method or meta refresh.

Comment: how can i alert after herder to inder2.php

Comment: use a JS or meta refresh for redirection. Tell you what: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. You're most likely outputting before header and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php on how to do a redirect using other methods. Also look at your console.

Comment: please show me some code i am confuse